# How to correctly export and import functions for cypress plugin index.ts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cypress

I am developing `plugin/index.ts` file where I place async functions eg. clearing the database or uploading files to the app, but it starts to grow and I think about a way to keep it clean and structured.

In [this](https://youtu.be/2HdPreqZhgk?t=265) video I see that there is a way to store functions in separate files and then export them using `module.exports = { function }` and then in the `index.ts` just import them using `require`.

But I can't have it working for my case.

This is a simplistic form of my `plugins/index.ts` file:

```
const uploadDocument = require('./documents');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config

  on('task', {
    clearDatabase: clearDatabase,
    uploadDocument: uploadDocument,
  });
  
  async function clearDatabase() { ... }
}
```

I decided to move the code of function `uploadDocument` to the `plugins/documents.ts` file:

[image]

and this is how the file `plugins/documents.ts` looks like:

```
imports...

async function uploadDocument(fileName: string) { ... }

module.exports = { uploadDocument }
```

And when I run the test with a task this way:

```
cy.task("uploadDocument", 'Very_light_file.pdf')
```

I get this error in Cypress:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with your module.exports and the import.

Try this,

```js
// document.ts

export async function uploadDocument(fileName: string) { ... }
// module.exports = { uploadDocument }
```

```js
// plugins/index.ts

import { uploadDocument } from './documents'
```

Comment: Shouldn't import be without `=`? Like this: `import { uploadDocument } from './documents';`

Comment: Yes, quite correct. Copy-paste problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the post, I can tell TS is mixed JS there. The example is in JS, you're using TS, so there is no module.exports.

Try a pure JS version, then later convert it to TS.

Comment: You were right! Thanks for the tip! I tried to export a function in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/plugins/index.ts](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/plugins/index.ts) you can see they change `module.exports` to:

```js
// cypress/plugins/index.ts

export default (on, config) => {
  config.env.defaultPassword = process.env.SEED_DEFAULT_USER_PASSWORD;
  config.env.paginationPageSize = process.env.PAGINATION_PAGE_SIZE;
  // Auth0
  //
  //
}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to just initialize my configuration from environment variables? What if I actually want to call a function I've defined in my plugins?   The Cypress documentation is unclear and lacking in this matter. They updated the process for making a plugin without providing solid examples.